# get cookies from browser using CORS

Tags: ajax, cookies, cors

I just heard about CORS, and wanted to know if it can help me in what I wanted to do.
There is a website that has CORS enabled on its server. If a user has a client session running on his browser, I wanted to access this from my server. I want this cookie to authenticate that person on my server.
Is that possible?
Can someone give me a very detailed guide, tutorial or a working example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, *if* the server responds with the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header. This header must be set by the server in order to exchange cookies. On the client side, they must set the XMLHttpRequest `withCredentials` property to `true`. See here for more details: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/